# NullPointerException in simple JOGL test case

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jogl

I'm trying a very simple JOGL tutorial using NetBeans and Swing and it seems no matter how I arrange things I keep getting a null pointer exception. Here is the code I am using (adapted from a tutorial):

```
package testjogl;

import com.jogamp.opengl.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class OpenGLTest extends javax.swing.JFrame implements GLEventListener {

    public OpenGLTest() {
        initComponents();        
    }

    public void doMain() {
        GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas();
        canvas.addGLEventListener(this);
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        this.getContentPane().add(canvas);  // <--- This is where the exception happens
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();      
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 
    }

    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) { }

    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();  
        gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
        gl.glLoadIdentity();  
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) { }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new OpenGLTest().doMain(); 
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

At the line where I add the canvas to my form, I get:
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException(null) breakpoint hit in sun.awt.image.OffScreenImageSource at line 189 by thread AWT-EventQueue-0.

I've tried several different JOGL tutorials and all of them keep throwing this exception when I add the canvas to my form. I couldn't find the code to OffScreenImageSource, but when I step through, it dies at line 1119 in Container.java. The code is:

```
invalidateIfValid();
if (peer != null) {
    comp.addNotify();  // <---- Dies right here
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this issue, but ... in addition to the answer already given, a wild guess: Try adding another `this.pack()` call **before** adding the canvas to the content pane. (This will "realize" the frame, and should allocate all internal resources - also the `comp` that seemed to be `null`).

Comment: @Marco13: Thank you! This lead me to discover the problem. I had an NPE breakpoint set up. Apparently, the code throws an NPE, then catches and ignores it. I was confused because if you ignore the NPE, the code I've posted still does nothing. But, I've found that if I add "canvas.setBounds(new Rectangle(0,0,640,480));" anywhere after creating canvas, things start working. I'm not sure why that would be necessary, or why none of the tutorials mention it, but that has fixed things for me. Thanks!

Comment: This might in fact be related to the canvas having a size of (0,0) when it becomes visible or so (whatever). Did you also try the suggestion from the answer?

Comment: Yes, I did. I forgot to respond to Guillaume, so I went back and did that. I think it's strange that, even if I add a layout and call "pack()", the canvas would still be of size (0,0), but apparently it is. Huh. Thanks for your help.

Comment: [Modern Hello Triangle](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/tree/master/jogl-samples/src/helloTriangle), Swing is mandatory?

Comment: You should use my rudimentary example as a starting point and replace the Frame by a JFrame: https://gist.github.com/gouessej/3420e2b6f632efdddf98

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you don't give enough time for Swing to initialize the component correctly with the OS GDI: As soon as you create the OpenGLTest() instance, you call doMain(). Give Swing some breath and it should work.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    OpenGLTest test;
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        test = new OpenGLTest()
    });
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        test.doMain(); 
    });
}
```

FYI, I didn't validate the syntax.

Comment: I had to rearrange the code a little to work, but it didn't help. In fact, it makes no difference even if I delay creating the canvas till after the frame has already been displayed (like in response to a button click). Thank you for the suggestion, but I think I've got it figured out.